# Extension of $k$-vector space structure to $k[x]$-module structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Be $k$ a field, $k[x]$ the polynomial ring over $k$, $V$ a $k$-vector space, and $f \in \text{End}_k(V)$. 
We want to see how the $k$-vector space structure can be extended to a $k[x]$-module structure in a unique way such that $(\forall v \in V)(xv = f(v))$.

I thought I had the answer, but I'm running into some trouble at the end. This is my reasoning:

We already have a $k$-module $V$, i.e. a map $\phi : k \times V \rightarrow V$ that satisfies the module axioms. We define the following map: 
\begin{eqnarray}
\psi : &k[x] \times V &\rightarrow V \\
&\left(\sum_{n=0}^∞ \lambda_nx^n, v\right) &\mapsto \phi(\lambda_0, v) + \sum_{n=1}^∞ \lambda_n f^n(v)
\end{eqnarray}
That way we'll have $\psi|_{k \times V} = \phi$ and $xv = \psi(x,v) = f(v)$. 
Checking the first two module axioms for $\psi$ is easy, but the third one ("$\psi(rs, v) = \psi(r, \psi(s,v))$") doesn't seem to work. On the one hand we have
\begin{align*} 
\psi\left(\sum_{n=0}^∞ \lambda_nx^n \cdot \sum_{n=0}^∞ \mu_nx^n, v\right) &= \psi\left(\sum_{n=0}^∞\left( \sum_{i=0}^n\lambda_i\mu_{n-i}\right)x^n, v\right) \\
&= \phi(\lambda_0\mu_0, v) + \sum_{n=1}^∞ \left(\sum_{i=0}^n\lambda_i\mu_{n-i} \right)f^n(v) \\
&=\phi(\lambda_0, \phi(\mu_0, v)) + \sum_{n=1}^∞ \lambda_nf^n \circ \sum_{m=1}^∞ \mu_mf^m (v)\\
&=\phi(\lambda_0, \phi(\mu_0, v)) + \sum_{n=1}^∞  \sum_{m=1}^∞ \lambda_n\mu_mf^{n+m} (v).
\end{align*}

On the other hand, we have
\begin{align*}
&\psi\left(\sum_{n=0}^∞\lambda_nx^n,\psi\left(\sum_{n=0}^∞\mu_nx^n, v\right)\right)  \\
&= \psi\left(\sum_{n=0}^∞\lambda_nx^n, \phi(\mu_0, v)+ \sum_{n=1}^∞\mu_nf^n(v), \right) \\
&= \phi\left(\lambda_0, \phi(\mu_0, v) + \sum_{n=1}^∞\mu_nf^n(v)\right) + \sum_{n=1}^∞\lambda_n\cdot f^n\left( \phi(\mu_0, v)+ \sum_{n=1}^∞\mu_nf^n(v)\right) \\
&= \phi(\lambda_0, \phi(\mu_0, v)) + \phi\left(\lambda_0,\sum_{n=1}^∞\mu_nf^n(v)\right) + \sum_{n=1}^∞\lambda_n\cdot f^n\left( \phi(\mu_0, v)+ \sum_{n=1}^∞\mu_nf^n(v)\right) 
\end{align*}

We need these expression to be equal, but now we've introduced a term that seems irreconcilable with the above expression: $\phi\left(\lambda_0,\sum_{n=1}^∞\mu_nf^n(v)\right)$. Am I silently using a rule that is not justified here?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but sometimes you denote the scalar product as, say, $\lambda \cdot v$ and in other parts you write $\phi(\lambda,v)$. Maybe that's causing a problem. For example, $\lambda_n f^n(v) = \phi(\lambda_n,f^n(v))$.

Comment: Wow I think you’re right! Completely forgot for a moment that $\phi$ is just scalar multiplication!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me simplify your notation. I will write $(\sum_{j=0}^n a_j x^j) \cdot v:= \sum_{j=0}^n a_j f^{j}(v)$. Note that $x^{j+k}(v) = f^{j+k}(v) = f^j (f^k(v)) = x^j \cdot (x^k \cdot v)$. Then we compute
$$  \left(\left(\sum_{j=0}^n a_j  x^j\right) \left( \sum_{k=0}^m b_k x^k \right)  \right) \cdot v 
=\left(\sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^m a_j b_k x^{j+k} \right)\cdot v
= \sum_{j=0}^n  \sum_{k=0}^m a_j b_k \left( x^{j+l} \cdot v \right)
= \sum_{j=0}^n  \sum_{k=0}^m a_j b_k x^j \cdot (x^k \cdot v)
= \sum_{j=0}^n a_j  x^j \cdot \left(\sum_{k=0}^m b_k x^k \cdot v\right)
= \left( \sum_{j=0}^n a_j  x^j \right) \cdot \left(\sum_{k=0}^m b_k x^k \cdot v\right) $$
Which is what we want to prove.

It is a fun exercise to think about when this $k[x]$-module will be free.

Comment: Thanks, I'm awful at polynomial products. This way of writing it is very helpful. Unfortunately I don't know what it means to be a free module (the course I'm taking is a bit over my head tbh). 
I do wonder now, does this mean we can conclude that End$_{k[x]}(V) = Z(\text{End}_k(V))$, or just the ones commuting with $f$? I'm asking because $f$ was arbitrary..?

Comment: No I suppose the latter. $\psi$ should actually be called $\psi_f$.

Comment: Free means that there exists a $k[x]$-basis. If $V$ is the zero vector space, then it is free (we have the empty set as a basis). Otherwise it will never be free. In fact, for every $v\in V$ exists $0\neq g \in k[x]$ such that $g\cdot v=0$ (use the theorem of Cayley-Hamilton to prove this), meaning already a family consting of a single vector is linearly dependent.

Comment: An element of $End_{k[x]}(V)$ is a $k[x]$-linear map $\varphi: V \rightarrow V$. In particular it is $k$-linear. Thus, we have $\phi\in End_k(V)$. In addition we want to have $$ (\varphi\circ f)(v) =\varphi(x\cdot v) = x\cdot \varphi(v) = (f\circ \varphi)(v)$$ Thus, we need $\varphi$ to commute with $f$.

Comment: On the other hand this is enough as we then have $\varphi(x^j\cdot v) = x^j \cdot \varphi(v)$ (why?) and thus $$  \varphi((\sum_{j=0}^n a_j x^j) \cdot v ) = \varphi ( \sum_{j=0}^n a_j (x^j \cdot v)) `= \sum_{j=0}^n a_j \varphi(x^j \cdot v) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j x^j \cdot \varphi(v) =  (\sum_{j=0}^n a_j x^j) \cdot \varphi(v)$$